# Html.RenderAction from different directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I am new to Asp.Net Mvc. This is my solution hierarchy

```
PROJECT
    --Area 
        -- Account
            --Controllers
            --Models
            --Views
                -- Edit.cshtml
    -- Contollers (this has an action method "SomeAction")
    --Models
    -- Views
         --Shared
           --Partial.cshtml
```

Actually I want to render Parial.cshtml in Edit.cshtml view. So I tried

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ControllerName", "SomeAction");}
```

But I got following error.

> The controller for path '/Account/Edit' was not found or
>   does not implement IController.

Not sure what am I missing ?

*If I remove @{Html.RenderAction("ControllerName", "SomeAction");} from my view. It works fine*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass area name to `RenderAction` method:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ControllerName", "SomeAction", new{area=""});}
```

Comment: My action method is not having any parameter. Then why should I pass area as route values?

Comment: Parameter area is not passed to your action method. It sets area where your controller should be.

Comment: Ok understood. But Action is not in Area. Its in root "Controller" folder and I am trying to render that action from View(Edit.cshtml) which is in Area.